# Is there an easy way in PHP to convert from strings like '256M', '180K', '4G' to their integer equivalents?

Tags: php

I need to test the value returned by `ini_get('memory_limit')` and increase the memory limit if it is below a certain threshold, however this `ini_get('memory_limit')` call returns string values like '128M' rather than integers.

I know I can write a function to parse these strings (taking case and trailing 'B's into account) as I have written them numerous times:

```
function int_from_bytestring ($byteString) {
  preg_match('/^\s*([0-9.]+)\s*([KMGTPE])B?\s*$/i', $byteString, $matches);
  $num = (float)$matches[1];
  switch (strtoupper($matches[2])) {
    case 'E':
      $num = $num * 1024;
    case 'P':
      $num = $num * 1024;
    case 'T':
      $num = $num * 1024;
    case 'G':
      $num = $num * 1024;
    case 'M':
      $num = $num * 1024;
    case 'K':
      $num = $num * 1024;
  }

  return intval($num);
}
```

However, this gets tedious and this seems like one of those random things that would already exist in PHP, though I've never found it. Does anyone know of some built-in way to parse these byte-amount strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're out of luck.  The PHP manual for [ini_get()](http://php.net/ini_get) actually addresses this specific problem in a warning about how ini_get() returns the ini values.

They provide a function in one of the examples to do exactly this, so I'm guessing it's the way to go:

```
function return_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

They have this to say about the above function:  "The example above shows one way to convert shorthand notation into bytes, much like how the PHP source does it."

Comment: Same problem as John's answer: doesn't handle the optional trailing B.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I was providing it mostly to illustrate how the PHP manual claims it's done.  This would work if you wanted to only analyze results of `ini_get()`, otherwise you'd have to modify it yourself.  The short answer to the posters question is really "No, there isn't a built-in method."

Comment: I was looking for this info in the description of the ini values and just about everywhere else other than the docs for the `ini_get()` function itself. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: Note the missing `break` in the switch

Comment: @PaulH break isn't missing, if suffix is "g", you really want to multiply by 1024 3 times. Version with break would be:
     `switch($last) {
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024 * 1024 * 1024; break;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024 * 1024; break;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024; break;
    }`

Comment: @PGBI I believe PaulH's point was that the breaks not being present is on purpose and thus notable as often switch statements will have breaks for each case.

Comment: @JohnKramlich Right, I interpreted the comment as a bug report. Now I feel stupid :)

Comment: @JohnKramlich thank you for clarifying my toughts. I should have written 'Note the `break`not present on purpose in the `switch` ' as you nicely do.

Comment: To handle warning messages and errors on newer versions of PHP, you need to do some char trimming. See below

Answer (score 8):

Or some shorter version, if you please

```
function toInteger ($string)
{
    sscanf ($string, '%u%c', $number, $suffix);
    if (isset ($suffix))
    {
        $number = $number * pow (1024, strpos (' KMG', strtoupper($suffix)));
    }
    return $number;
}
```

Comment: ...and an *even shorter* variation: `function memToBytes($m){sscanf($m,'%u%c',$n,$s);if(isset($s)){$n=$n*pow(1024,strpos(' KMG',strtoupper($s)));}return$n;}`

Comment: ...and to return a string **"Memory Usage %"**: `function memPct(){return number_format(100*memory_get_usage()/memToBytes(ini_get('memory_limit')),1)+'%';}` (Note: 2nd function requires the [1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336581/is-there-an-easy-way-in-php-to-convert-from-strings-like-256m-180k-4g-to#comment113708645_4613049) function.)

Comment: @ashleedawg well, 'shorter' in the sense that it consumes fewer bytes when typing it out, but it's the same code as akond's.

Comment: @akond, I'd accept your answer as the legitimate one, since, unlike the selected solution, your code deals nicely with the (potentially) trailing B.

Comment: This does not seems to work for a value like: "1.2M"

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP website for [`ini_get()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php):

```
function return_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't actually handle the optional B on the end.

Comment: When does it have a B on the end? Is that platform specific?

Comment: Look at the OP's regex. There's an optional B at the end.

Comment: I added the 'B' and the white-space matches to the regular expression to make the function more generally useful than just being able to parse the values returned by `ini_get()`. The more general version will also handle decimal sizes as well, i.e.: 2.25MB

Comment: Note the missing `break` in the switch

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of a slight variation on what you're doing:

```
function int_from_bytestring($byteString) {
  $ret = 0;
  if (preg_match('!^\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+))\s*([KMNGTPE])B?\s*$!', $byteString, $matches)) {
    $suffix = " KMGTPE";
    $index = strpos($suffix, $matches[2]);
    if ($index !== false) {
      $ret = $matches[1];
      while ($index--) {
        $matches *= 1024;
      }
    }
  }
  return intval($ret);
}
```

Comment: I actually like the original version even more then yours: no loops. At least no explicit loops :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you will get an error with newer versions of PHP if the value has a CHAR at the end of it, you might need some extra testing:

```
private function toBytes($str){
    $val = trim($str);
    $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
    if (!is_numeric($last)) {
        $val = substr($val,0,strlen($val)-1);
        switch($last) {
            case 'g': $val *= 1024;
            case 'm': $val *= 1024;
            case 'k': $val *= 1024;
        }
    }
    return $val;
}
```

This works with no warnings

Answer (score 0):

even if the solutions above are correct, the `switch` statement without a `break` is not very intuitive and for an improved readability, to express what is really going on, I would rather do it this way:

```php
/**
 * @return int maximum memory limit in [byte]
 */
private static function takeMaximumFootprint()
{
    $memory = ini_get('memory_limit');
    $byte = intval($memory);
    $unit = strtolower($memory[strlen($memory) - 1]);
    switch ($unit) {
        case 'g':
            $byte *= 1024 * 1024 * 1024; break;
        case 'm':
            $byte *= 1024 * 1024; break;
        case 'k':
            $byte *= 1024; break;
    }

    return $byte;
}
```

Comment: This works if you only have G/M/K at the end; but it's possible to either have nothing, or two characters such as GB/MB/KB. The OP handles those cases nicely.

Comment: ... as for the lack of a `break` statement, taking advantage of a very useful but not universally known feature, I guess that all it takes is to place a comment (explaining also _why_ it works) 