# get byte value from shorthand byte notation in php.ini

Tags: byte, php

Is there any way to get the byte values from the strings returned from functions like `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` and `ini_get('post_max_size')` when they are using [shorthand byte notation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes)?  For example get 4194304 from 4M ?  I could hack together a function that does this but I would be surprised if there wasn't some built in way of doing this.

Comment: If you read on from the link you posted, the php docs tell you how to do it...

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1336581/632951

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[The paragraph you linked to](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) ends:

> You may not use these shorthand notations outside of php.ini, instead
>   use an integer value of bytes. **See [the ini_get() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) for an
>   example on how to convert these values.**

This leads you to something like this (which I have slightly modified):

```
function return_bytes($val)
{
    $val  = trim($val);

    if (is_numeric($val))
        return $val;

    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    $val  = substr($val, 0, -1); // necessary since PHP 7.1; otherwise optional

    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Use it [like so](http://codepad.org/SmJhMmlj):

```
echo return_bytes("3M");
// Output: 3145728
```

There is no built-in function to perform this task; recall that, really, INI settings are designed for use *internally* within PHP. The PHP source uses a similar function to the above.

Comment: just saw that - have some free rep!

Comment: Be carefull in 7.1 you'll need to separate value from modifier before do multiplications

$val = substr($val, 0, -1);

Comment: Been looking for a decent solution for this for a while, really nice solution.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, works like a charm! However, I'm wondering why I get wrong results when I'm putting breaks after each case in the switch loop? Using PHP 7.2 on Apache

Comment: @Piet: Because that completely changes the semantics. With my code, when `$last` is `'g'` you [correctly] multiply `$val` by 1024 _three times_. With your change, there is only ever one multiplication no matter what `$last` is. You removed the fall-through. Why did you add `break` statements?

Comment: Note: returns `10` if f.e. `100` given. (have a look at http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php#96996 too)

Comment: @cottton: Yes, if you provide an unexpected input, you will get an unexpected output. That other version is alright, except for the undocumented magic numbers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is what bothers me. I would expect false on wrong|unexpected input OR the original value to be returned (same type as given, not converted to string).

Comment: @cottton: You can make that modification trivially if you like. I prefer to document preconditions and let the mis-user suffer the consequences of violating them, rather than forcing obedient users to waste cycles on mandatory extra checks. But this quick example is certainly not the most robust function in the world, I'll grant you.

Comment: After the `trim()` you should add `if (is_numeric($val)) { return $val; }` For plain numeric values.

Comment: @powtac Yep, could do (but see my comment to cotton!)

Answer (score 2):

Gah! Just found the answer on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

Just needed to RTM...

```
function return_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my suggestion which should be future-proof (with regard to PHP Versions 7++)!

```
function return_bytes($val, $gotISO = false) {        
    // This is my ultimate "return_bytes" function!
    // Converts (not only) the PHP shorthand notation which is returned by e.g. "ini_get()"
    // Special features:
    // Doesn't need regular expression and switch-case conditionals.
    // Identifies beside "Kilo", "Mega" and "Giga" also "Tera", "Peta", "Exa", "Zetta", and "Yotta" too!
    // Ignores spaces and doesn't make no difference between e.g. "M" or "MB"!
    // By default possible commas (,) as thousand separator will be erased. Example: "1,000.00" will "be 1000.00".
    // If ($gotISO == true) it converts ISO formatted values like "1.000,00" into "1000.00".
    $pwr = 0;
    if(empty($val)) return 0;
    $val  = trim($val);
    if (is_numeric($val)) return $val;
    if ($gotISO) {
        $val = str_replace('.','',$val); // wipe possibe thousend separators (.)
        $val = str_replace(',','.',$val); // convert ISO comma to value point
    } else {
        $val = str_replace(',','',$val); // wipe possibe thousend separators (,)
    }
    $val = str_replace(' ','',$val);
    if (floatval($val) == 0) return 0;
    if (stripos($val, 'k') !== false) $pwr = 1;
        elseif (stripos($val, 'm') !== false) $pwr = 2;
        elseif (stripos($val, 'g') !== false) $pwr = 3;
        elseif (stripos($val, 't') !== false) $pwr = 4;
        elseif (stripos($val, 'p') !== false) $pwr = 5;
        elseif (stripos($val, 'e') !== false) $pwr = 6;
        elseif (stripos($val, 'z') !== false) $pwr = 7;
        elseif (stripos($val, 'y') !== false) $pwr = 8;
    $val *= pow(1024, $pwr);
    return $val;
}
```

... have fun with it!

Comment: oh boy, imagine the days when we'll be dealing with yottabytes. Probably for website logos for the new Retina 100K display.

Comment: You will get "A non well formed numeric value encountered" notice from the `$val *= power(1024, $pwr);` line because `$val` is a string. Maybe separate the `floatval` from the designator? Maybe something like `$num = floatval($val); $designator = trim(substr($val,strlen($num),1));` and use `$num` in the calculation and `$designator` in the if statements?

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot of  solution to solve this problem and there should have been a builtin function to solve this. In any case two things to highlight about this problem:

1. This is very specific to PHP's shorthand byte values as explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes and should only be used in this context.
2. Most modern IDEs will give warning for `switch` statements without `break`.

Here is a solution that covers everything:

```
/**
 * Convert PHP's directive values to bytes (including the shorthand syntax).
 *
 * @param string $directive The PHP directive from which to get the value from.
 *
 * @return false|int Returns the value of the directive in bytes if available, otherwise false.
 */
function php_directive_value_to_bytes($directive) {
    $value = ini_get($directive);

    // Value must be a string.
    if (!is_string($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    preg_match('/^(?<value>\d+)(?<option>[K|M|G]*)$/i', $value, $matches);

    $value = (int) $matches['value'];
    $option = strtoupper($matches['option']);

    if ($option) {
        if ($option === 'K') {
            $value *= 1024;
        } elseif ($option === 'M') {
            $value *= 1024 * 1024;
        } elseif ($option === 'G') {
            $value *= 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither one of the Version shown above will work with PHP 7.2x anymore, as I found out.By use of this,with PHP 7.0 + 7.1, it works, but not with PHP 7.x
Ernie

```
private function return_bytes ($val) {
        if(empty($val))return 0;
        $val = trim($val);
        preg_match('#([0-9]+)[\s]*([a-z]+)#i', $val, $matches);
        $last = '';
        if(isset($matches[2])){
            $last = $matches[2];
        }
        if(isset($matches[1])){
            $val = (int) $matches[1];
        }
        switch (strtolower($last)){
            case 'g':
            case 'gb':  
            $val *= 1024;
            case 'm':
            case 'mb':
            $val *= 1024;
            case 'k':
            case 'kb':
            $val *= 1024;
        }
        return (int) $val;
    }
```

Comment: From what I understand, `gb`, `mb` and `kb` are invalid designators and if they are in your `php.ini` they will be ignored altogether and assume you mean *bytes*. So `4gb` will really be 4 bytes. Look at the note at the bottom of this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#120016

Answer (score -3):

Here is one way.

```
$str=ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $str, $match);

echo ($match[0] * 1024 * 1024); // <--This is MB converted to bytes
```

Comment: What if the value wasn't in megabytes?

Comment: Then the above code would have to be adjusted for a different conversion. Most settings in php.ini use MB, including the examples asked about above.

Comment: So this answer is incomplete.